# wp_login_form() redirecting to wp-login.php eventhough login crediantials are correct

Tags: php, wordpress

While i'm trying to login with the below form, it is redirecting to wp-login.php for correct username and password too.

```
<?php
         $uargs = array(
        'echo'           => true,
        'redirect'       => admin_url(), 
        'form_id'        => 'loginform-custom',
        'label_username' => __( '' ),
        'label_password' => __( '' ),
        'label_remember' => __( 'Remember Me' ),
        'label_log_in'   => __( 'Sign In' ),
        'id_submit'      => 'wp-submit',
        'remember'       => false,
        'value_username' => NULL,
        'value_remember' => false ); ?>
    <?php wp_login_form( $uargs ); ?>
```

Above mentioned is my syntax. I'm using it in header. And also I'm using "Theme My Login" plugin. 
What I'm missing can any one help me please.

Comment: Where you want to redirect after login? for home try `'redirect' => site_url( '/ ' )` or `redirect` => site_url( '/mypage/ ' )`

Comment: Sorry, actually what the issue is this form is not making the user to login, this form is simply redirecting to wp-login.php insted of logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my issue is solved, I updated the permalink structure to `/%postname%/` then it is working.